# convex decreasing function with limit example

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I'm trying to find a function that is strictly decreasing function for $x\geq 0$ and has a positive limit, i.e. $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. I was thinking $$f(x)=\frac{a}{x^2+b}+c$$ for some positive constants $a,b,c$. However this is actually a concave-convex function. What are some great strategies when formulating a function? What are some examples that satisfy my conditions?

Comment: Can you precise the domain of your functions? Also it is not clear what you're looking for regarding convexity. Can you update your question accordingly?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1} + 1$ is a simple example. The limit is 1 and the function is strictly decreasing, satisfying all the conditions. Where is the problem?

Comment: $f(x)=exp(-x)+1\to1$ as $x\to+\infty$. Also, $f$ is convex and strictly decreasing. Unfortunately most of the "strategies" are just learning a library of common convex functions and their properties [arising from doing lots and lots of exercises from convex analysis books :) ]